# How do you edit the vertical line that line breaks the code in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I tried setting it in preferences, disabling word wrap, changing word wrap column, trying alt z, but the line is always there and forces the code to wrap into 1/3 of the available space which makes long code hard to read

Comment: That is just a `ruler`, see `Editor: Rulers` in your settings.  So you can get rid of the vertical line by making sure that setting is empty or deleted altogether.  But it is just a guide, it doesn't have any effect on whether the line actually wraps at the ruler.  It sounds like `Editor: Word Wrap` set to `off` isn't doing anything for you.  Could there be an extension that is interfering?  Disable all extensions and see if wrap stops happening.

Comment: @Mark oh thank you yes that was the issue, i had the dart extension installed and it overrides the setting in vs code.

Comment: Hey guys, do your know how put that line guide in Visual Studio 2022?